# setTypeface nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've come into yet another problem again, this time its even more confusing:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView cityData;
    TextView updatedData;
    TextView detailsData;
    TextView currentTemperatureData;
    TextView weatherIcon;
    Typeface weatherIcons;
    Handler handleWeather;

    public MainActivity() {
        handleWeather = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cityData = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.city_field);
        updatedData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_field);
        detailsData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details_field);
        currentTemperatureData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_temperature_field);
        weatherIcon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);

        weatherIcons = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "weather.ttf"); //fonts found from https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons 
        weatherIcon.setTypeface(weatherIcons);
```

Over here, in this code, my error lies in the `weatherIcon.setTypeface(weatherIcons);`, where it receives a NullPointerException even if I switched the positions of the last two lines of which its origin I cannot find after a long time searching. (Same too for searching an answer here on stackoverflow)
Do you know what is causing this error and could you please help me point it out?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about how an Activity works. Don't use an `Activity` constructor to initialize your variables (and not mentioning the call to `setContentView` missing), it has its own lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to provide layout to your activity. You have to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity)
```

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost
>   all activities interact with the    user, so the Activity class takes
>   care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with
>   **setContentView(View)**.

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Yes! Yes it worked! I did not know `setContentView` went hand in hand with `onCreate`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try below modified code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView cityData;
        TextView updatedData;
        TextView detailsData;
        TextView currentTemperatureData;
        TextView weatherIcon;
        Typeface weatherIcons;
        Handler handleWeather;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_xml_file);

            cityData = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.city_field);
            updatedData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_field);
            detailsData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details_field);
            currentTemperatureData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_temperature_field);
            weatherIcon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);

            weatherIcons = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "weather.ttf"); //fonts found from https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons 
            weatherIcon.setTypeface(weatherIcons);
```

Comment: Yes! This works too! `setContentView` is important to the overall `onCreate`!

Comment: Always remember to call setContentView() before setting View's components